# Overwrite field description in an image widget

Tags: 8

I have an image field (multiple).

In the node form, the [ImageWiget](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21ImageWidget.php/class/ImageWidget/8.5.x) has a `process` method that adds previews and form fields for images that have already been uploaded.

The description for the title tag is hard-coded on line 278: `'#description' => t('The title is used as a tool tip when the user hovers the mouse over the image.')`. We are actually showing the title as a caption and not a tooltip.

How can I override the description?

Comment: Have you found a way around ?

Answer (score 0):

Using hook_field_widget_form_alter You can do this:

```
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  if ($context['field']['field_name'] == 'field_image_top') {
    // Loop through the element children (there will always be at least one).
    foreach (element_children($element) as $key => $child) {
      // Add the new process function to the element

      $element[$key]['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process';
    }
  }
}

function MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process($element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form) {
  // Change the title field label and description

 $element['title']['#description'] = 'SOME NEW DESCRIPTION HERE.';
 return $element;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this answer mixes D7 code `element_children()` with D8 code so it's not working :/

Comment: Try using [\Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element.php/function/Element%3A%3Achildren/) (and note that Element::children returns the array keys)

Answer (score -1):

Using a hook_form_alter() you will be able to change that '#description' inside the structured $form array.

Comment: Can't find it in D8.9.x $form array